# Make render items from top to bottom first and from left to right second, clear css/html solution, no serverside no js

Tags: html, css, layout

i have code http://jsfiddle.net/edkrwtpn/1/

html:

```
<div class="items-container" >
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.items-container{
  width: 100%;
}

.items-container > span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}
```

items automatically rendered like this:[image]

but i need them automatically rendered like this:

[image]

Does it possible to make it behave like desired with only html/css, without js or server side processing?

Number of items can be any. So 5 items it is not constant value.

**Update**

**Item width must be 33% always. So row must contain only 3 items, i do not need to grow number of items in row.**

So if i will add more items, they must turn from this:
[image]

to this:

[image]

Comment: Check out writing mode and `vertical-lr` in CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Columns

```css
.items-container {
  columns: 3 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="items-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: still doesn't match OP's expected output. :)

Comment: He still has first row 1 2 3 4, and then 5 6 7 and then  8 9 10. But you have 12 3 4, then 5 6 7 8 and then 9 10. I am also surprised your answer is accepted, and that means he was wrong in his expectation.

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted, i updated question, the direction must flow from top to bottom first, from left to right second, like described in title.